Sign Up authentication using Firebase unsuccessful
"firebase": "^10.11.0"
I am working on my OTP verification using Firebase for my authentication function. But I got an error like this :
\*\* Failed to send OTP: Firebase: The phone verification request contains an invalid application verifier. 
The reCAPTCHA token response is either invalid or expired. 
(auth/invalid-app-credential).\*\*

const formatPhoneNumber = (phoneNumber) => {
    // Thêm mã quốc gia +84 và bỏ số 0 đầu tiên nếu cần
    if (phoneNumber.startsWith("0")) {
      return "+84" + phoneNumber.slice(1);
    }
    return phoneNumber;
  };
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      // Kiểm tra và khởi tạo reCAPTCHA nếu chưa có
      if (!window.recaptchaVerifier) {
        window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
          "recaptcha-container",
          {
            size: "invisible", // hoặc 'normal' nếu muốn hiển thị
            callback: (response) => {
              console.log("reCAPTCHA solved, can proceed with OTP sending.");
              sendOtp();
            },
            "expired-callback": () => {
              console.error(
                "reCAPTCHA expired. Please solve the CAPTCHA again."
              );
            },
          }
        );
      } else {
        await sendOtp(); // Nếu verifier đã tồn tại, chỉ cần gửi OTP
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during OTP sending:", error.message);
    }
  };
  const sendOtp = async () => {
    const appVerify = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    const formattedPhoneNumber = formatPhoneNumber(formData.phoneNumber); // Format số điện thoại
    console.log("sdt ne", formattedPhoneNumber);
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(formattedPhoneNumber, appVerify)
      .then((confirmationResult) => {
        console.log("sdt", formattedPhoneNumber);
        // Store confirmation result globally
        window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult; // Save OTP verification result globally
        console.log("gui otp thanh cong");
        localStorage.setItem("phoneNumber", formattedPhoneNumber);
        navigate("/otp", { state: formData });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.code === "auth/invalid-app-credential") {
          console.error(
            "reCAPTCHA token expired or invalid. Please reload reCAPTCHA."
          );
          window.recaptchaVerifier.clear(); // Xóa reCAPTCHA khi gặp lỗi
          window.recaptchaVerifier = null; // Tái khởi tạo reCAPTCHA khi gặp lỗi
        }
        console.error("Failed to send OTP:", error.message);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!recaptchaVerifier) {
      const verifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
        "recaptcha-container",
        {
          size: "invisible",
          callback: (response) => {
            console.log("reCAPTCHA solved, can proceed with OTP sending.");
          },
          "expired-callback": () => {
            console.error("reCAPTCHA expired. Please solve the CAPTCHA again.");
          },
        }
      );
      setRecaptchaVerifier(verifier);
    }
  }, [recaptchaVerifier]);

I have setup a Register form and also a Recaptcha container
{/\* Recaptcha container \*/}
\<div id="recaptcha-container"\>\</div\>

I don't know what this error is, so please help me thank you guys.
I've setup a firebaseConfig, also for the RecaptchaVerifier as well as Enable the Phone Method on Firebase Console. Also for the billing of the Blaze Plan
My expectation is when click on the button, it will send the OTP to the phone number i typed on the formData, and redirect to the OTP component for user to verify
My region is Vietnam, so I also setup a formattedNumber function to change ít to "+84"
